# Assign image to imagebox on pointermoved event

Tags: c#, image-processing, user-controls, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 App. I have developed a user control. The user control is in a shape of a location bar and the user control has a imagebox inside it. 
The usercontrol will appear when any user taps the screen for a long time.At this point of time ,the image box should get the image from the pixels nearbythe click event. Now when the user moves his finger around the app , the image box should display pixels around that area only. Once the user releases his finger , the control gets disabled .

So the problem is , I want to update the image box in the control wherever the finger goes .

Comment: How is this related to C#-6.0?

Comment: Instead of mocking kindly Try to provide a solution. I need the code help in C# and wanted C# developers working on Windows 8.1 and I think it utilizes C# 6.0 .

Comment: @Apoorv The final version of C# 6.0 hasn't been released yet, Windows 8 apps usually use C# 5.0. Also, I don't think Paulo intended to mock you.